# Override properties when including a psake script in an other psake script

Tags: powershell, properties, build, task, psake

I am new to psake and I have this issue: I have 2 psake scripts:

(1): base_tasks.ps1:

```
properties{ 

$a = "hello"

$b = "hi"

}

task One{
  Write-Host $a
}
```

(2): install.ps1

```
Include .\base_tasks.ps1

properties{ 

$a = "Goodbye"

$b = "Adjeu"

}

task default -depends One
```

Now, is it possible to override the properties and variables from file 1? I want to use file 1 as "base tasks" and use those tasks in the install.ps1 and override the properties. Or do I have to do that an other way? I will invoke install.ps1 and use my $a and $b from install.ps1.

- DanceAlot

Comment: not sure if this exactly answers your question: https://github.com/psake/psake/wiki/How-can-I-override-a-property-defined-in-my-psake-script%3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [source](https://github.com/psake/psake/blob/master/psake.psm1), it looks like `Properties` is just a function:

```
function Properties {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=1)][scriptblock]$properties
    )
    $psake.context.Peek().properties += $properties
}
```

So when you call it again, it will just add the properties again.

The properties are then converted into variables like so:

```
foreach ($key in $properties.keys) {
        if (test-path "variable:\$key") {
            set-item -path "variable:\$key" -value $properties.$key | out-null
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, ok. I understand, thanks for clarifying that matter. So there is no way of achieving what I need? Or am I using psake the wrong way:)